# In Python, how do I sort an array of JSON objects by a value in each object?

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, sorting

I'm using Python 3.7.  I have an array of JSON objects.  I would like to sort the array of objects based on one of the values ("score") in each JOSN object.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the sort function.  I tried this

```
>>> arr = [{'score': 10, 'name': 'Bob'}, {'score': 15, 'name':'Susan'}, {'score': 1, 'name': 'Skippy'}]
>>> arr
[{'score': 10, 'name': 'Bob'}, {'score': 15, 'name': 'Susan'}, {'score': 1, 'name': 'Skippy'}]
>>> arr.sort(key=json['score'], reverse=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'json' is not defined
>>> arr.sort(key=json['score'], reverse=True)
```

but I can't figure out how to reference the JSON object from the "key" part of the sort function.

Answer (score 4):

Use either a `lambda` function (with a parameter named `json` or whatever):

```
arr.sort(key = lambda json: json['score'], reverse=True)
```

Or, `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

arr.sort(key = itemgetter('score'), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sorted(iterable, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as follows:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> arr = [{'score': 10, 'name': 'Bob'}, {'score': 15, 'name':'Susan'}, {'score': 1, 'name': 'Skippy'}]
>>> sorted(arr, key=itemgetter('score'), reverse=True)
[{'score': 15, 'name': 'Susan'}, {'score': 10, 'name': 'Bob'}, {'score': 1, 'name': 'Skippy'}]
```

`itemgetter('score')` allows `sorted` to access the `key` element in of each dictionary in your list of dictionaries and order the list accordingly.